# Python 3.2 statistics normal distributtion

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a package compatible with Python 3.2 that can calculate the integral for a standard normal distribution (x). That is, calculate P(X< x) for standard normal distr. Scipy is supporting this function but I cannot find a version that is compatible with 3.2. Is there any other package?

Comment: Or better, help [porting SciPy to Py3](http://new.scipy.org/faq.html#when-will-scipy-support-python-3-x)! NumPy for 3.x is underway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a stats person, but I do know of a stats module on [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stats) that is Python 3 compatible.